# Is there a more efficient way to find the smallest Vector3 combination from a single number?

Tags: python, loops, unity-game-engine, vector, lua

I'm trying to find the smallest combination of vector3 from a single number, I have working code so far but it's really not efficient.

To demonstrate, let's say a user enters the number *n*, the function should output the combination of 3 numbers (*x, y, z*) with the smallest sum while still being able to multiply to the original number *n*.

So if the user enters 100 as n the x, y, and z should be 4, 5 and 5. (or (5, 5, 4); (5, 4, 5)).

I'm doing 3 for loops to calculate separate values of x, y, and z. It works great with small numbers but it becomes incredibly calculation heavy as *n* increases. I'm looking for any ways I can change the method of calculation that would make this faster. I'm open to approximation algorithms as this doesn't need to be 100% accurate.

I originally wrote it in Lua but the problem isn't directly related to one language.

```lua
function CalculateVector(Size)
    local Vectors = {}
    local Lowest = math.huge
    local Index = nil
    for x = 0, Size, 1 do
        for y = 0, Size, 1 do
            for z = 0, Size, 1 do
                if Size - (x * y * z) == 0 then
                    table.insert(Vectors, Vector3.new(x, y, z))
                end
            end
        end 
    end
    table.foreachi(Vectors, function(i, v)
        local Combined = v.X + v.Y + v.Z
        if Combined < Lowest then
            Lowest = Combined
            Index = i
        end
    end)
    return Vectors[Index]
end
```

Same code in Python in case someone doesn't know Lua syntax.

```py
class Vector3:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.X = x
        self.Y = y
        self.Z = z

def CalculateVector(Size):
    Vectors = []
    Lowest = Size + 3
    Index = None
    for x in range(Size):
        for y in range(Size):
            for z in range(Size):
                if Size - (x * y * z) == 0:
                    Vectors.append(Vector3(x, y, z))
    for i,v in enumerate(Vectors):
        Combined = v.X + v.Y + v.Z
        if Combined < Lowest:
            Lowest = Combined
            Index = i
    return Vectors[Index]
```

Comment: What is the maximal value of `n`?

Comment: *n* could be any number that's more or equal to 1, and is less than Lua's `math.huge`. A good abstract limit would be 10,000 as I don't plan on running it above that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factorize `n` and test every split of all its prime factors into 3 sets

```lua
function split_number_into_factors_having_min_sum(n, factors)
   assert(n > 0 and factors > 0)
   local primes = {}
   local degrees = {}
   local terms = {}
   local p = 2
   local step = {4, 1, 2, 0, 2}
   local m = 0
   while n > 1 do
      if p * p > n then
         p = n
      end
      if n % p == 0 then
         local d = 0
         repeat
            d = d + 1
            n = n / p
         until n % p ~= 0
         m = m + 1
         primes[m] = p
         degrees[m] = d
         terms[m] = {}
      end
      p = p + step[p % 6]
   end
   local parts = {}
   for j = 1, factors do
      parts[j] = 1
   end
   local best_sum = math.huge
   local best_parts = {}
   local process_next_prime

   local function split_in_terms(sum, qty, k)
      if qty < factors then
         local max_val = parts[qty] == parts[qty + 1] and sum > terms[k][qty] and terms[k][qty] or sum
         qty = qty + 1
         local min_val = qty == factors and sum or 0
         for val = min_val, max_val do
            terms[k][qty] = val
            split_in_terms(sum - val, qty, k)
         end
      else
         local p = primes[k]
         for j = 1, factors do
            parts[j] = parts[j] * p^terms[k][j]
         end
         process_next_prime(k)
         for j = 1, factors do
            parts[j] = parts[j] / p^terms[k][j]
         end
      end
   end

   function process_next_prime(k)
      if k < m then
         split_in_terms(degrees[k + 1], 0, k + 1)
      else
         local sum = 0
         for j = 1, factors do
            sum = sum + parts[j]
         end
         if sum < best_sum then
            best_sum = sum
            for j = 1, factors do
               best_parts[j] = parts[j]
            end
         end
      end
   end

   process_next_prime(0)
   table.sort(best_parts)
   return best_parts
end
```

Usage:

```lua
local t = split_number_into_factors_having_min_sum(100, 3)
print(unpack(t))  --> 4 5 5
```